# selenium web driver - how to use waitFor for AJAX

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add explicit wait before each and every web element in the test script

My code has

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
                     .
                     .
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("name")));

driver.findElement(By.id("name")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Create_title_01");
```

The error I see is:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait$1.apply(FluentWait.java:176)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait$1.apply(FluentWait.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:201)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:174)
```

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits) for doing it in a single command, if you want to. ...and the code for `presenceOfElementLocated(By)`, please?

Comment: Hi , thx. Did not write any code for presenceOfElementLocated(By).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For using **presenceOfElementLocated** and other AjaxCondition methods

you should use

> org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions

class. Your code should be like this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("name")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using waitForElementPresent or a waitForElementNotPresent depending on the event of your AJAX call.

However, if you still like to use wait.until here is how I do (and it works)

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(wedriver1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
.....
button.Click();
wait.Until(webdriver1 => webdriver2.webelement.GetAttribute("style").Contains("display: block"));
```

I gave an example of attribute change in the condition that Until method takes. You could do something like..

driver.findElement(By.id("name")).displayed (for your condition inside wait.until.

Comment: If you're checking for the existence of an element, you shouldn't be using `driver.findElement()` as it will throw an Exception if the element is not on the page or not visible. You should use `driver.findElements()` or add a `try-catch` block around `findElement()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the following line after the `WebDriverWait wait` initialization:

```
wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```